# Icons: Use Data-URIs or Embedded Fonts?

Tags: css, icons, embedded-fonts, data-uri

I have a set of about 10 monotone icons 25x25 or less. Which has better performance:

1) Embed them in CSS with data URIs

2) Load them as a font ([IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/app/), etc)

Loading as a font seems like it might be less beneficial because it makes an http: call, unless I... 2b) Embed the font files themselves.

I've been using IcoMoon for the last month on this project, but it's a bit tedious if I need to make changes to the SVGs and reupload to the app. The CSS is also quite a bit messy when dealing with fonts vs. images.  It seems like I might save headache with base64 encoding the SVGs and be done with it.

So what would you say is the best way? Or an alternative to those? I'm optimizing for Webkit, Mozilla and IE8+.

Comment: IE8? That doesn't support SVGs... nor WOFF. Unless you mean including EOT or VML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends™.

It seems like data URIs are slower on mobile, but icons less than 1KB can have better perf when embedded. It also depends on how often the images are used per-page — data URIs apparently have to be decompressed each use, so if you’re using them many times a page that might affect performance.

Unfortunately no one seems to have compared data URIs and @font-face icon fonts for mobile performance yet. Ideally, do some real-world RUM testing and publish your findings ^_^ If you do, please also check embedding an icon font in CSS as a Base64-encoded data URI :D

Finally, there are some [Grunt plugins](http://gruntjs.com/plugins/font) that can automate the workflow for you, and using `[data-icon]`-style embedding for the icon font decreases the CSS mess (attr() is supported in IE8+).

- [Why Inlining Everything Is NOT The Answer](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/why-inlining-everything-is-not-the-answer/) — Guy Podjarny, Perf Planet 2011
- [CSS Sprites vs. Data URIs: Which is Faster on Mobile?](http://www.mobify.com/blog/css-sprites-vs-data-uris-which-is-faster-on-mobile/) — Peter McLachlan, August 29 2013

PS Sorry for the ramble, I want this info too…

Comment: Thanks for the articles. I'll probably dig through those when I get some downtime. Since posting this in February, we ended up falling out of love with base64, simply due to it's unwieldy-ness. I imbedded a sprite with 16 icons on one of our websites (they are full color, so ico fonts aren't an option anyways) and love how they load immediately with the content. Gzip makes the css file size increase negligible....

Comment: For another of our projects, we use icons all over the place. In fact, we based our redesign heavily on them. I've gotten much more used to using IcoMoon so updating font files are less of a hassle with that tool. I have switched between data-URIs and source files, and really now we are just making decisions based on workflow. It definitely is a big improvement over using images for many reasons. Much more performant and we can treat them like fonts in the browser.